# Is this matrix of full rank ? Matrix given by a directed graph

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

I constructed this matrix $M$ given a directed graph $G = (E,V)$ :

$$M \in \mathcal M^{|E| \times |V|}$$
with this definition.
On every line it corresponds to an edge. If the arc is going from a vertex $v$, then in the corresponding column $v$ there is a $1$. If it goes to $v$, there is a $-1$.

I think this matrix is of full rank. Do you have any counterexample ?
Maybe if there is a cycle?

Comment: You are definitely going to need a few more hypotheses. Just take a graph with three nodes and one edge. Your matrix has at least one zero column and cannot be full rank. This holds for any disconnected graph.

Comment: i was also thinking that with disconnected graph it does not work. But maybe the construction I did has a common name ? maybe there is a theorem about that?

Comment: Yes indeed, it is called an [incidence matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix).

Comment: I have usually been talking about incidence matrices for the matrix vertex vertex. In my optimization class, I called the node-edge matrix something more similar but as in the incidence matrix, there are only 1 and 0. Here i put also $-1$. With the node-edge matrix, i ve proven that the determinant is 0 in the case that there is an even cycle. I think that if there is an odd cycle, with this new construction, the matrix is also not of full rank

Comment: The vertex/vertex matrix is the [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix). There may be $-1$ entries in the incidence matrix (take a closer look at the Wikipedia article). Since you are from EPFL, you may look at the [page in French](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrice_d%27incidence). Since node rank and column rank [are the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Proofs_that_column_rank_=_row_rank), whatever you prove for the node-edge matrix holds true for the edge-matrix as well.

Comment: @BillO'Haran The graph with three nodes and one edge has $M = \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, which has full rank (rank 1).

Comment: @MishaLavrov You're right. I got a little carried away here. But add the same edge going backwards to that graph and we are all good for a counter-example :)

Answer (score 1):

The matrix will always have rank less than $|V|$, because the sum of all the columns (that is, over all vertices) gives the $0$ vector. So if $|V|\le|E|$, $M$ cannot possibly have full rank (which is full column rank in this case).

More generally, adding up all the columns in a connected component (connected ignoring the edge orientation) gives the $0$ vector. So a graph with $k$ connected components gives a matrix $M$ with column rank at most $|V|-k$.

In fact, the rank of $M$ is exactly $|V|-k$, because $M^{\mathsf T}M$ is the [Laplacian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) of the underlying undirected graph. The rank of $M^{\mathsf T}M$ is $|V|-k$, because the multiplicity of the $0$ eigenvalue is always the number of connected components. Therefore the rank of $M$ is $|V|-k$.

$M$ can still have full row rank if $|E|=|V|-k$. There is only one way for this to happen. If $V_1, V_2, \dots, V_k$ are the connected components, then the graph must have at least $|V_i|-1$ edges spanning $V_i$, for at least $|V|-k$ edges total; equality holds just if each connected component is a tree (ignoring edge orientation).

So $M$ has full row rank exactly when the underlying undirected graph is a forest.